# SVG + jQuery, circle r animates differently in chrome

Tags: jquery, svg

I have two circles that need to grow and shrink to the original size, slightly out of sync of each other. It works in most browsers except for Chrome. In Chrome the circles shrink to 1px and stay that way (tries to go negative values, see console errors).

I suspect it has to do with the fact that Chrome is transitioning towards SVG2, thus implementing the r animation in the CSS instead of the attribute.

here is a working example that renders differently in Chrome vs IE/Firefox.

**html**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" width="400" height="400" class="">
    <circle class="ring" r="30" cx="-50" cy="0" ></circle>
    <circle class="ring" r="30" cx="50" cy="0" ></circle>
</svg>
```

**js**

```
function animateRing(ring,delay)
{
    ring.delay(delay).animate(
        {r:1},
        {
            duration: 700,
            step: function(val) { jQuery(this).attr("r",35-5*(1-2*val)*(1-2*val)) }
        })
}

function animateRings()
{
    jQuery('circle.ring').each(function(idx){
        animateRing(jQuery(this),idx*300)
    })
    setTimeout(animateRings,3000)
}
animateRings()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1b1gLe15/3/

What is the best way or workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome got confused by the dummy content {r:1}

therefore, it was fixed by changing the function as below:

```
function animateRing(ring,delay)
{
    ring.css("dummy",0)
    ring.delay(delay).animate(
        {dummy:1},
        {
            duration: 700,
            step: function(val) { jQuery(this).attr("r",35-5*(1-2*val)*(1-2*val)) }
        })
}
```